# How to flatten a nested dict and use inner values on collision

Tags: python, dictionary, flatten

**Question**

For the following dictionary:

```
{'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52}}}
```

I want to create a new dictionary without the `remove_me` or `world` keys.

**Edit update:**

To summarise, I wanted to do the following:

If the values of an item are a nested dictionary. Update the new dictionary with the inner result while removing the current key value from the main dict.

If the values of an item are not a nested dictionary, update the new dictionary with the key, value.

The accepted answer covers this.

**What have I tried?**

```
{k:v for (k,v) in d.items() if not k == 'remove_me'}
```

yields:

```
{'id': 1, 'label': 'hello'}
```

not exactly what I need as I'm dropping the nested dict.

**Desired output:**

```
{'id': 1, 'label': 'hello','keep_me': 52}
```

Comment: Are there other similar keys to which this would apply? If it's only the specific key in question it seems it would be easier to just manually assign that key-value pair

Comment: What do you want to do if "remove_me" has multiple keys, or has a key that isn't "world"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
d = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52}}}
for k, v in list(d.items()):
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for i in v:
           if isinstance(v[i], dict):
               d.update(v[i])
           else:
               d.update(v)
        del d[k]
print(d)
```

Output

```
{'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'keep_me': 52}
```

This code will check if the values of each item are a dict and if so it will update the dict with the inner result and remove the current key value from the main dict. 
By that, in the end, the d dict will stay only with a key and a string value without nested dicts.

Comment: This is simply deleting nested dicts **not** specific keys. This fails with a dict like `d = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52, 'test':2}}}` It also incorrectly deletes good keys with dicts such as `d = {'id': 1, 'label': {'test':'hello'}}`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Ah, the second one's the counterexample I was looking for with my earlier comment.

Comment: Yes @MateenUlhaq you can just change `remove_me` to `dont_remove_me` for disaster to strike.

Comment: Sidenote, I had to change `for k, v in d.items():` to `for k, v in list(d.items()):` in order to avoid `RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration`

Comment: @awarrier99 Thank for that I change the code according to your note

Comment: No problem, I was just about to comment on the fact that the logic would have to be changed as `list(d.items())` creates an static list of the initial items, but you addressed that with your update

Comment: @LeoArad it still deletes good keys. For example: `d = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'dont_remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52}}}`  returns `{'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'keep_me': 52}` What happened to `dont_remove_me`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer now it's supporting this cases as well

Comment: @LeoArad it seems doomed to failure if the task is to delete specific keys and the code does not use those keys. So now this fails: `d = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'remove_me': {'dont_remove': {'keep_me': 52}}}`  and removes `dont_remove`. Everything you are doing only considers the shape of the dict not the specific keys.

Comment: It also doesn't remove `remove_me` here: `d = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'remove_me': 52}`

Comment: The request was to flatten a dictionary not to check if the key value is remove_me because of that it's doesn't metter what is the key value only if it's a dictionary or not.

Comment: @LeoArad the OP seems to agree with you since they selected this. I suppose it's possible to read this in more than one way: `I want to create a new dictionary without the remove_me or world keys.`  and `Conditionally extract keys and values` but I read that to mean they wanted to conditionally remove certain keys.

Answer (score 3):

```py
dico = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52}}}

# Just what you have done
new_dico = {k:v for (k,v) in dico.items() if not k == 'remove_me'}

# Plus this line
new_dico.update(dico['remove_me']['world'])

print(new_dico)
# {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'keep_me': 52}
```

Inspired by what I have read here, a flatten function for the main dict, whatever deep one of your key-dict is:

```py
dico = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52}}}

def dFlatten(dico, d = {}):
    for k, v in dico.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            dFlatten(v)
        else:
            d[k] = v
    return d
dico = dFlatten(dico)
print(dico)
# {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'keep_me': 52}
```

For instance with a deeper dico :

```py
dico2 = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'stuff1': {'stuff2': {'remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52}}}}}
dico2 = dFlatten(dico2)
print(dico2)         
# {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'keep_me': 52}
```

With several deep keys with the same dFlatten function

```py
dico3 = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'deep': {'L1': {'L2': 52}}, 'remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52}}}
dico3 = dFlatten(dico3)
print(dico3)         
# {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'keep_me': 52, 'L2': 52}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might need to be a bit more specific about the structure of your dictionary, and how to handle multiple keys. Regardless, here's one recursive method that fits your description and attempts to preserve as many keys as possible.

```
def clean_kvp(k, v, invalid_keys=["remove_me", "world"]):
    if k not in invalid_keys:
        return [(k, v)]
    if not isinstance(v, dict):
        return []
    return [
        (kkk, vvv)
        for kk, vv in v.items()
        for kkk, vvv in clean_kvp(kk, vv)
    ]

def clean_dict(d):
    return {
        kk: vv
        for k, v in d.items()
        for kk, vv in clean_kvp(k, v)
    }
```

A couple of tests:

```
>>> d = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52}}}
>>> clean_dict(d)
{'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'keep_me': 52}

>>> d = {
...     'id': 1,
...     'label': 'hello',
...     'remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52, 'test': 2}}
... }
>>> clean_dict(d)
{'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'keep_me': 52, 'test': 2}

>>> d = {'id': 1, 'label': {'test': 'hello'}}
>>> clean_dict(d)
{'id': 1, 'label': {'test': 'hello'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flattening a dictionary is a whole thing in itself. Does this accomplish your goal? (Untested, I'm typing on my phone a.t.m.):

```
def flattenDict(myDict, blacklist):
  returnDict = {}
  for key, val in myDict:
    If isinstance(val, "dict"):
       myDict.update(flattenDict(val))
    elif key in blacklist:
       continue 
    elif val in blacklist:
        continue
    returnDict[key] = val
  return returnDict 

cleanDict = flattenDict(myDict, ["remove_me", "world"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done in a general case with a single recursive function with something like:

```
def remove_keys(d, keys):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d 
    ret = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        clean = remove_keys(v, keys)
        if k not in bad_keys:
            ret[k] = clean
        else:
            if isinstance(clean, dict):
                ret.update(clean)

    return ret

bad_keys = ['remove_me', 'world']

d = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52}}}
remove_keys(d, bad_keys)
# {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'keep_me': 52}

d = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'remove_me': 52}
remove_keys(d, bad_keys)
# {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello'}

d = {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'dont_remove_me': {'world': {'keep_me': 52}}}
remove_keys(d, bad_keys)
# {'id': 1, 'label': 'hello', 'dont_remove_me': {'keep_me': 52}}
```