python - Combine structured JSON with remaining JSON
I have this structured df (json) which includes another json and I want to combine them to access all the values:
{
  "index": "exp-000005",
  "type": "_doc",
  "score": 9.502488,
  "source": {
    "verb": "REPLIED",
    "timestamp": "2022-01-20T08:14:00+00:00",
    "in_context": {
      "screen_width": "3440",
      "screen_height": "1440",
      "build_version": "7235",
      "question": "Hallo",
      "request_time": "403",
      "status": "success"
    }
  }
}

The result I want is the following:
{
  "index": "exp-000005",
  "type": "_doc",
  "score": 9.502488,
  "verb": "REPLIED",
  "timestamp": "2022-01-20T08:14:00+00:00",
  "screen_width": "3440",
  "screen_height": "1440",
  "build_version": "7235",
  "question": "Hallo",
  "request_time": "403",
  "status": "success"
}

How can I combine this structured json to one unstructured json? In R I used tbl_json. Maybe there is something similar for python?

What do you mean by "combined"? This is an ordinary JSON object, with some of the values being other JSON objects. What end result do you want?

I also wonder what you mean. Do you perhaps want to convert this nested data structure to a flat one instead?

I edited my question, I hope this helps. I did this in R with tbl_json, so I am looking for something similar

With Python, you basically want to flatten a nested dict. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62105447/how-to-flatten-a-nested-dict-and-use-inner-values-on-collision and see if  that can help you.

Does this answer your question? How to flatten nested python dictionaries?

If you are coming from r-lang then you will likely want to look at pandas and specifically pandas.json_normalize() and/or pandas.read_json()

yes I tried it with pandas, but then I still have the same problem that I have this nested JSON which I want to combine / flatten. Is there a way of doing it with pandas (as a pandas df)?

json_normaliz() has parameters meta_prefix, record_path, and record_prefix. Check out How to read a JSON file with nested objects as a pandas DataFrame?

Looks like you want to flatten the dict and only pick the values of the keys which are themselves dictionary.
Here is a recursive approach:
from pprint import pprint

d = {
    "index": "exp-000005",
    "type": "_doc",
    "score": 9.502488,
    "source": {
        "verb": "REPLIED",
        "timestamp": "2022-01-20T08:14:00+00:00",
        "in_context": {
            "screen_width": "3440",
            "screen_height": "1440",
            "build_version": "7235",
            "question": "Hallo",
            "request_time": "403",
            "status": "success",
        },
    },
}


def flatten(d: dict, result_d: dict | None = None) -> dict:
    if result_d is None:
        result_d = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            flatten(v, result_d)
        else:
            result_d[k] = v
    return result_d


new_d = flatten(d)

pprint(new_d, sort_dicts=False)

output:
{'index': 'exp-000005',
 'type': '_doc',
 'score': 9.502488,
 'verb': 'REPLIED',
 'timestamp': '2022-01-20T08:14:00+00:00',
 'screen_width': '3440',
 'screen_height': '1440',
 'build_version': '7235',
 'question': 'Hallo',
 'request_time': '403',
 'status': 'success'}


this should also work in jupyterLab right?

@threxx It works wherever a piece of python code can work including jupyterLab.

Okay It worked for the json. Could you maybe show me how I would do this for an array of jsons like this? Is there a way to iterate over all the jsons in this array, call the flatten function and then re-add it to the array as a json? So that I have an array with multiple, flattened jsons

The flatten function above returns a new dict. @threxx The process is mostly how you described it. You can use a list comp for that. [flatten(d) for d in list_of_jsons]. This gives you a new list containing flattened jsons.
